Using Firebase Admin in Fresh Framework on Deno Deploy
The Problem
I am building a project in the Deno Fresh framework that uses Firebase admin server-side to fetch a value from a Firebase Realtime Database and render it on a page. My project works locally and when ran on my own server however when I deploy my project to Deno Deploy the site hangs when I visit any page that fetches data from the Firebase.
I have the appropriate Firebase admin credentials set as an environment variable in Deno Deploy and a string exists in the Realtime Database under /test. No errors are present in the Deno Deploy logs. By adding console.log() statements after each line in the handler, it appears the code hangs at const value = (await ref.get()).val();. I have provided my code below.
What do I need to change for this to work in Deno Deploy?
Code
/firebase.ts
import { initializeApp, cert, ServiceAccount } from "npm:firebase-admin/app";
import { getDatabase, Database } from 'npm:firebase-admin/database';

let database: Database;
if (!Deno.args.includes("build")) {  // This prevents firebase initialization during build
  const firebaseCreds: ServiceAccount = JSON.parse(Deno.env.get("FIREBASE_ADMIN_KEY") || "{}");
  const firebase = initializeApp({
    credential: cert(firebaseCreds),
    databaseURL: "https://my-database-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/"
  });
  database = getDatabase(firebase);
}

export { database };

/routes/index.tsx
import { database } from "../firebase.ts";

export const handler: Handlers = {
  async GET(_req, ctx) {
    const ref = database.ref("/test");
    const value = (await ref.get()).val();  // this is the line that hangs
    return ctx.render(value);
  }
}

export default function Home(props: PageProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      { props.data }
    </div>
  );
}


Most likely there's an error you are not seeing. Put a try/catch block around any await you have and log any errors.

@FrankvanPuffelen I have attempted this but there are no errors being thrown. The await ref.get() promise just never resolves in the deno deploy environment.

Hmmm... the only thing I can imagine for that is if the client can't connect to the database. So make sure your https://my-database-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/ is exactly correct. --- I'm not sure if you can still enable debug logging with firebase.database.enableLogging(true), but if so: that might provide some hints too.

I've experienced the exact same issues when using Firebase Admin in Deno Deploy. My guess is that it's a runtime issue. What is odd is that no error is ever thrown nor is there anything in the logs. Writing to Firestore just causes it hang indefinitely. Seems that the SDK just doesn't work at the moment when deployed on Deno Deploy but works just fine locally.
